# Função em Java equivalente a pack("v",int) em Perl/PHP

Tags: php, java, perl

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função no Java equivalente a função `pack("v",numero)` do Perl e PHP.

No perl/php:

```
pack("v",numero) = unsigned short (always 16 bit, little endian byte order)
```

No Java:

```
?
```

Comment: Essa http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_pack.htm ?

Comment: Sim, queria saber como consigo gerar o resultado equivalente no java.

Comment: Cara, no Java o tipo `short` é *signed* com ordenação *big endian*, o Java 8 começou a ter algum suporte a tipos *unsigned* (através de métodos em *wrappers* como `Integer` e `Long`). Como você gostaria de armazenar o seu numero convertido? Para que vai utilizá-lo? O Guava possui um [LittleEndianDataOutputStream](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LittleEndianDataOutputStream.html) capaz de escrever `shorts` para uma `stream` *little endian* se é isso que você precisa.

Comment: Sockets. Obrigado, resolveu o problema.